# add some elements from 2 txt files into a third file

Tags: java, file

I have done the reading and writing of the files, but I have a problem. I don't know why it shows only the last line of the files. In the part with reading the lines from Person.txt, when I get out of the while loop, I want to show the p.getName() for each line and it shows only the last line. How can I fix this?

here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListaHobby {

 String line="";
 Hobby h = new Hobby();
 Persoana p = new Persoana();
 BufferedWriter bw = null;
 ArrayList<Persoana> listOfPersons;
 ArrayList<Hobby> listOfHobbies;
  public void writeListaHobbies(){
    try{
      listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Persoana>();
      FileReader  file1 =new FileReader("Persoane.txt");


      listOfHobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
      FileReader file2 = new FileReader("Hobby.txt");


      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

      while((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null){

         if(!line1.trim().contains("ID")){
          String[] attributes = line1.split(";");// split it at every ";"

            //Person person = new Person();           // make a new person
            p.setNume(attributes[1]);
            p.setPrenume(attributes[2]);
            p.setDataNasterii(attributes[3]);
            p.setProfesie(attributes[4]);


             listOfPersons.add(p);
         }
      }

     System.out.println(p.getNume());
      while((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null){


          if(!line2.trim().contains("ID")){
            String[] attributes = line2.split(";");  // split it at every ";"

                      // make a new person
            h.setNume(attributes[1]);
            h.setDescriere(attributes[2]);
            h.setNrPers(attributes[3]);
            h.setElemNecesar(attributes[4]);

            listOfHobbies.add(h);

          }

      }
     System.out.println(h.getNume());

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("PersHobby.txt");
      bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

     for(int i = 0;i < listOfPersons.size(); i++) {

        //for(int j = 0 ; j < listOfHobbies.size();j++) {

             if((p.getId())== (h.getId()))
                 p.addHobby(h);

             String s = p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume() +
                     ": " + h.getNume() + ", " + h.getNume();
             System.out.println(s);
             bw.write(s);
             bw.newLine();
     }
      bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error opening file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding the same person to your list. You need to create a new object at each iteration by uncommenting the commented line. Once you have done that, you can remove the class member (p) as it is not needed any longer because you store the persons in the ArrayList.

The same comment applies to the list of hobbies.

```
  while((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null){

     if(!line1.trim().contains("ID")){
      String[] attributes = line1.split(";");// split it at every ";"

        Persoana p = new Persoana();  // <~~~ you need to create a new person for each line
        p.setNume(attributes[1]);
        p.setPrenume(attributes[2]);
        p.setDataNasterii(attributes[3]);
        p.setProfesie(attributes[4]);


         listOfPersons.add(p);
     }
  }
```

Comment: but when i read p.getNume() outside the while it shows nothing

Comment: p only exists within the while loop (read about scope and local variables if you don't understand why). To access it outisde the loop, you need to use the arraylist (for example listOfPersons.get(0) will return the first person you have added to the list) => you can read about how to use collections.

Comment: thank  you for your advice.I'm new to java and i'm still learning.you really did help me

Comment: @Laura No problem. It is good practice to accept the answer that helped you most. You can [read here about how accepting answers works and why it is important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179508). You should also go back to your previous questions and accept an answer if you received a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the single instances of `Person` and `Hobby` to add to the respective lists. Instead, for each (unique?) ID found, create `new Person`, `new Hobby` and use them to add to the list.

```
p = new Person();  
p.setXXX...  
...
```

Similarly for Hobby.

```
h = new Hobby();
h.setXXX...   
...
```

Unless you do this, you only be adding the latest found data to the same `person` and `hobby` objects to the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add people and hobbies when reading each line of the input file and iterate through both the people and hobbies when writing to file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListaHobby {

 String line="";
 Hobby h;
 Persoana p;
 BufferedWriter bw = null;
 ArrayList<Persoana> listOfPersons;
 ArrayList<Hobby> listOfHobbies;
  public void writeListaHobbies(){
    try{
      listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Persoana>();
      FileReader  file1 =new FileReader("Persoane.txt");


      listOfHobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
      FileReader file2 = new FileReader("Hobby.txt");


      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

      while((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null){

         if(!line1.trim().contains("ID")){
          String[] attributes = line1.split(";");// split it at every ";"

            p = new Persoana();           // make a new person
            p.setNume(attributes[1]);
            p.setPrenume(attributes[2]);
            p.setDataNasterii(attributes[3]);
            p.setProfesie(attributes[4]);


             listOfPersons.add(p);
         }
      }

     System.out.println(p.getNume());
      while((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null){


          if(!line2.trim().contains("ID")){
            String[] attributes = line2.split(";");  // split it at every ";"

            h=new Hobby();
            h.setNume(attributes[1]);
            h.setDescriere(attributes[2]);
            h.setNrPers(attributes[3]);
            h.setElemNecesar(attributes[4]);

            listOfHobbies.add(h);

          }

      }
     System.out.println(h.getNume());

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("PersHobby.txt");
      bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

     for(int i = 0;i < listOfPersons.size(); i++) {
        p=listOfPersons.get(i);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < listOfHobbies.size();j++) {
             h=listOfHobbies.get(j);
             if(p.getId())== h.getId()))
                 p.addHobby(h);

             String s = p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume() +
                     ": " + h.getNume() + ", " + h.getNume();
             System.out.println(s);
             bw.write(s);
             bw.newLine();
         }
     }
      bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error opening file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```